# Domino DXLImporter Exception

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

Getting an exception when importing a .dxl file with a large collection of documents.  The importer gets most of the way through, then fails with the following exception:

"Base64 byte stream contains invalid data or is too large to store in a single note item"

Some googling turned up a bug that was supposed to have been fixed via an SPR AGUD8D7V55 related to large attachments.  See link below:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/bpmpblog.nsf/dx/dxl-importing-issue-may-want-hotfix

Anyone know if this bug was ever fixed, or if it was accidentally re-introduced in 9.0.1?

thanks

Comment: You tagged it with XPages - so are you using the Java based importer? You actually should. Then you could split the document (SAX it in) into individual junks to fail only on specific ones

Comment: This is a good idea and I would have tried this approach if this were happening in PROD.  Changed my approach to the problem (see other comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed in 8.5.2FP2 and 8.5.3 onwards. More details here.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/fixlist.nsf/Public/E461469D3BEA868E8525783000736F00?OpenDocument

I'm not aware of a regression.

If you break it down to multiple subsets of the documents does it work? If not, is there a particular document? And if so is any Base64 data correct/too large?

Comment: Haven't gone that far yet.  Wanted to find out if this bug still exists or not...  Seems like it shouldn't be an issue based on your answer.  I'll see if I can isolate the problem doc... maybe its just a one off... lets hope :).  I'll update this thread if I find anything odd.  thanks for responding so quickly.

Comment: I've changed my approach to divide and conquer.  Instead of exporting one potentially big dxl file, I'm exporting each document individually to the server's file system and wrapping them in a zip.  So far all tests have worked for importing / exporting against the same set of documents (close to 10k) with a minor hit to execution time...  thanks for the help